# RecyclerView onScrolled Dy value is not dependable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-animation

Am trying to achieve an animation in my app by using the amount of scroll in a recycler view to animate outside views that moves at the same pace as the scroll change

Currently am using OnScrolled function and depending on dy parameter but this value is sometime not accurate and throwing unexpected values like sometimes scrolling up it gives positive values and while scrolling it might give negative value that extremely the opposite and it's gives a jerk kind of animation that jumps up and down.

Am trying to change the top margin of Top UI elements while the recyclerView is scrolling check image bellow :

[image]

Sample code of what am currently doing :

```
          override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
           
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
          
            val currentOffset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
            Timber.d("$TAG currentOffset = $currentOffset")
    
                animateUpdateMarginTop(topElementUi, currentOffset , duration = 0)
```

Comment: Some thing like this? https://github.com/valkriaine/Bouncy

Comment: Or you can post a video/gif of the animation you're trying to achieve

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah am not trying to animate elements of the recyclerView 

i just shared a sample code .

Comment: I can't see your sample code

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah just updated with an image and code.

Comment: Why would you alter margins instead of applying translation Y? Altering layout params forces a measurement pass which might indeed cause UI jank. Also you might want to look into nested scrolling solution which lets you hook into (and intercept) actual scrolling and lets you do pixel perfect animations.

Comment: Hi @Pawel i tried all of you said 
and due to my project UI complexity ( Big project ) i have to use margin instead of translation because that Top UI block is not a single layout in my case it's a set of layouts that are in separate xml layouts, and the only solution in my case as of now is to play with the top margin while scrolling. i tried with nested scroll view, it's becoming very slow to scroll.